# How to convert a inconsistent dictionary to .ini dynamically using python?

Tags: python, dictionary, configparser

I have a use case where I ll be getting complex dictionaries as inputs in a inconsistent hirarchy.
one use case would be like below :

```
pro : 1
rel : 1.2
del : demo
cb :{
 a : b
}
cd : {
 en : {
  b : a
}
}
cc : {
a : b
}
```

I used something like this : -

```
def jsonToDict(data):
    d = data
    res = defaultdict(dict)

    def dict2ini(d, root):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                _key = '%s.%s' % (root, k) if root else k
                if v:
                    dict2ini(v, _key)
                else:
                    res[_key] = {}
            elif isinstance(v, (str,int, float)):
                res[root] = {k:v}
    dict2ini(d, '')

    config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
    for key in sorted(res.keys()):
        config.add_section(key)
        for subKey, value in res[key].items():
            config.set(key, subKey, value)

    with open('example.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)
```

but the above doesn't process all the values present in my dict but only the first line in each section. I went through [ConfigParser][1]. But I am unable to find a solution to my use case can someone suggest me some workaround this also please note the above data is not fixed it will be changing according to our needs.

EXAMPLE INI :

```
pro = 1
rel = 1.2
del = demo

[cb]
a=b

[cd.en]
b=a
## suppose if multiple data is present in cd then 
[cd]
b=a
[cd.en]
b=a
## end

[cc]
a=b
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete; it accesses a dictionary `res` that isn't defined anywhere.  Could you please also fix the indentation of your code?
Do you want to support arbitrarily nested dictionaries?  Could you give an example how the resulting ini file is supposed to look?

Comment: I fixed the above also i gave how output ini should look like but its not fixed view, as long as the json content is embedded to ini and is properly understandable any format will do .. also yes i do want to support arbitarily nested dictionaries @SvenMarnach

Comment: So if any format will do, how about `json=<json_string>`?

Comment: @SvenMarnach by any format I meant pattern but the output has to be in .ini/properties format only

Comment: Well, it is.  There's a single key called `json`, and the value for that key is a JSON string.

Comment: yup that will be fine as long as i get it in the above displayed fashion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, take a close look at your code.  In `dict2ini` you iterate over a list of items in `d`:

```
    for k, v in d.items():
```

And if `v` is a scalar value, you add it to the `res` dictionary...but you always use the same key:

```
        elif isinstance(v, (str, int, float)):
            res[root] = {k: v}
```

So for each item in the dictionary, you're going to override the previous value of `res[root]`. With a few minor changes, I think you'll get closer to what you want:

```
def dict2ini(d, root):
    section = res[root]
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            _key = '%s.%s' % (root, k) if root else k
            if v:
                dict2ini(v, _key)
            else:
                section[_key] = {}
        elif isinstance(v, (str,int, float)):
            section[k] = v
dict2ini(d, '')
```

This gives me as output:

```
[DEFAULT]
pro = 1
del = demo
rel = 1.2

[]

[cb]
a = b

[cc]
a = b

[cd]

[cd.en]
b = a
```

You obviously have a few additional things to fix there, but hopefully that sets you in the right direction.